# GetAce() failing with - ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, acl

I'm attempting to do some ACL modification with some C++ code in Visual Studio. I'm stumbling into several issues, one of which is that, when I try to read the ACEs off the existing ACL using GetAce(), the call to the function fails and it returns error 87, ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

The ACL in question includes four entries, and the first two are read successfully, but the second two fail with the invalid parameter error.

Here's the snippet of code that I'm running, I'd appreciate any insight anyone has on it.

```
// filePath variable is passed in from command line...
PACL existingAcl;

if(GetNamedSecurityInfo(filePath, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, &existingAcl, NULL, &securityDescriptor) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    OutputDebugString("Could not retrieve ACL.\n");
    return false;
}

const int numEntries = existingAcl->AceCount;

for(DWORD i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS* thisAce;

    if (!GetAce(existingAcl, i, (LPVOID*) &thisAce)) {
        OutputDebugString("Failed to retrieve ACE.\n");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your compiler [warned you](https://godbolt.org/z/Mszn5jnY7). That's not something you should ignore.

Comment: @273K I stripped out most of the actual extra code - like checking for results of GetNamedSecurityInfo and passing in a file path rather than defining a static one. The "real code" has those things in it.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, but that's not actually the issue - the file is read perfectly fine, and my actual code doesn't use a constant like that, it is passed in via a command line argument.

Comment: This code snippet looks ok. The error is somewhere in the not shown code. Perhaps the not shown code corrupts the memory block referenced by `existingAcl`.

Comment: @273K Good point, thanks - I'll scrutinize the rest of my code and make sure that I'm not inadvertently messing items that might be pointed to by the members of the `existingAcl` structure.

Comment: Better to show real code; that way you don't risk introducing new problems that do nothing but waste peoples' time.

Comment: @273K - You were spot-on, I was modifying a member of `existingAcl`, probably in a way which caused problems for the rest of the iterations of retrieving ACEs. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yeah, good point - I was just trying to avoid posting all 400+ lines of code in a single post, but apparently should have been a little more verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was modifying a member of one of the ACEs retrieved from the ACL directly, within the loop, which was most likely adjusting pointers or memory in such a way that broke things with memory allocation, etc. Thanks to @273K for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Hello @VirtuallyNick, You can mark it as accepted If you have resolved your issue.